# What are the steps to re-write this exponent in the new form

Tags: linear-algebra, probability

I am looking at this formula, which is a multivariate gaussian distribution and I am not sure how they expanded the exponent to the new form. I have also looked into a bit on what $x^T \Sigma^{-1}x$ means exactly. From my understanding $\Sigma^{-1}$ is the precision matrix and it's diagonal will tell us how clustered our data is around the mean. But the off diagonal I am not very clear on.

[image: Formula]

Comment: First of all are you clear on what dimensions (i.e. vector or matrix) the objects involved have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Do you know how to expand $$(a - b) \cdot c \cdot (a - b) = (a - b)^2 \cdot c,$$ where $a,b,c$ are real numbers?

Comment: Thanks, I understand how to do this. In terms of matricies it seems to me with your hint that it's the same thing except we maintain order and x^2 becomes xx* where x* is the transpose of x

Comment: @JacobB That's correct.